# How to add an HTML block in Thank You page of Shopify?

Tags: shopify

I am building an app in Shopify and one of the requirements sent to me by Shopify is to ***include navigation to the customer portal** on the **Order Status page***.

I created an app web pixel following instructions from here: https://shopify.dev/docs/api/pixels/pixel-extension#app-web-pixels and I'm able to make it work. I see it logging in my Thank You page.

Here's a sample code I have:

```
import { register } from '@shopify/web-pixels-extension'

register(({ analytics, init, browser }) => {
  console.log('browser object', browser.window)
  console.log('browser.window object', browser.window)

  const { window } = init.context

  // Subscribe to Page Viewed event
  analytics.subscribe('page_viewed', async (event) => {
    console.log('window', window)
    console.log('window.document', window.document)
    console.log('event.context.document', event.context.document)

    // Check if customer is on Thank You page
    if (event.context.document.title.startsWith('Thank you')) {
      const sectionContent = event.context.document.querySelector(
        '.section__content'
      )
      const secondContentBox = sectionContent.querySelector(
        '.content-box:nth-child(2)'
      )

      const newDiv = event.context.document.createElement('div')
      newDiv.innerHTML = `Add an HTML block here for navigation`

      sectionContent.insertBefore(newDiv, secondContentBox)
    }
  })
})
```

Since Web Pixels run on a sandbox, I don't have access to the `window` object. I can't figure out how I'll be able to *inject* an HTML block in this page.

Here's the error I'm getting:

[image: console errors]

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to accomplish adding an HTML block in here please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've posted this same question in Shopify Community. I was told to use [Checkout UI Extensions](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/checkout-ui-extensions/2023-07/extension-targets-overview#supported-typ-locations).

See here: https://community.shopify.com/c/extensions/how-to-add-an-html-block-in-thank-you-page-of-shopify-using-web/m-p/2185711/highlight/true#M849